# Home folder button "buggy" after opening specific program (Maple 15)

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, home-directory, directory

I've recently done a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit (not wubi).

I had no problems, until I installed the program "Maple 15". Once I open Maple, the Home-button at the bar to the left, acts like the "Maple-15"-button. Additionally, the usual "Maple 15"-button doesn't appear in the same bar.

While Maple 15 is opened, I can't use the home-button to open the home folder. Once I close Maple 15, I can use the home-button to open the home-folder. However, the home-button and the home-folder aren't "connected" anymore, so it just opens a new folder every time, instead of re-opening the already opened folder.

If I uninstall Maple 15, the problem is solved.

I did not have this problem on Wubi.

Thank you,
Jesper

Comment: Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

**strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file**

Launching installer...


I'm thinking perhaps the line in bold is causing the problem. I don't remember that happening previously (in wubi).

It is this file I'm trying to install: Maple15LinuxX86_64Installer.bin

Answer (score 1):

I've seen behavior like this before, when something claims a directory as its mimetype. You can fix it by editing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and removing the offending line.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling ubuntu in specific English (and not Danish) and choosing "no" to make a desktop icon during the installation, it works.

Not sure which part did it.